# Curl cannot find the certificate file

Tags: php, curl

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

In the home directory, I created a .curlrc file, with the following in it:

```
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

When I do:

```
ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

produces:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 phptools phptools 274340 Jan 18 20:03 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

However, when I try doung a curl call from my php script, I get the following error:

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

The certificate is there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the `.curlrc` file in your home directory won't have any effect on curl in PHP.

But the issue is most likely that `CAfile` needs to be an actual file, not a path.  When curl goes to check those, it's failing because that isn't a file.

You might try correcting that using these [php.ini settings](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.configuration.php) or using `CURLOPT_CAINFO` in your code (e.g. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt');`

If things (cURL, OpenSSL, GnuTLS) were built with CAfile as a path instead of a file, this needs to be corrected at compile time.

Comment: I did have that in my code, I did not have the specific file name, just the path, as I thought the docs said to specify the path, not the exact file name. Your suggestion worked